# Failing to connect to the postgress statefulset database installed from stable/postgresql helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

Do you guys have played with the [stable/postgresql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) helm chart?

I successfully install the release using this command within a GKE context

```
$helm install --name pg-set -f ./values-production.yaml stable/postgresql --set postgresqlDatabase=nixmind-db
```

It went fine, but I can't further connect to my cluster for ckeck/tests..., cause it fails connecting to the database due to password.

I tried all the following way but got the same error :

```
$export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default pg-set-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
$kubectl run pg-set-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0 --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db
```

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>      pod "pg-set-postgresql-client" deleted
>      pod default/pg-set-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

```
$export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default pg-set-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
$kubectl run pg-set-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0 --env="POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db
```

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>   pod "pg-set-postgresql-client" deleted
>   pod default/pg-set-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

```
$export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default pg-set-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
$kubectl run pg-set-postgresql-client --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0 --env="POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db
```

> If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
>
> psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
>     pod default/pg-set-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

```
$export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default pg-set-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
$kubectl run pg-set-postgresql-client --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0 --env="POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db
```

> If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
>
> psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
>    pod default/pg-set-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

Thy to connect localy to the client and run the command

```
$kubectl run pg-set-postgresql-client --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0 --env="POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- /bin/bash
```

> If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

```
I have no name!@pg-set-postgresql-client:/$ env
.............................................................................
POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=m7RWxRvpSk
POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=postgres
POSTGRESQL_NUM_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLICAS=0
POSTGRESQL_INITDB_ARGS=
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.63.240.1
NAMI_VERSION=1.0.0-1
.............................................................................
```

```
I have no name!@pg-set-postgresql-client:/$ psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db
```

> Password for user postgres:
>   psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

It seems to be a problem being submitted several time, but without real solution... 
How do you guys test this release after installation? 
What am I missing? Is the password retrieved from the cluster secrets the one configured on the master database? 
May be  this command `psql --host pg-set-postgresql -U postgres -d nixmind-db` tries to access the slave and not master really? 
Why the `psql` client doesn't even read the password from environment variables as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It's all OK.

I was characters issue with my terminal, the password retrieved from cluster credentials is the good one, and the database is accessible.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @nixmind Can you pls. elaborate it. I am also facing this same issue.  If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
psql: error: connection to server at "postgresdb-postgresql" (10.233.47.199), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
 Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
pod "postgresdb-postgresql-client" deleted
pod kvib-dev/postgresdb-postgresql-client terminated (Error)

Comment: I used postgresdb-postgresql-hl  The headless service and it worked.